# How do i select data from multiple table and display it with php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php    
$dbhost = 'localhost'; 
$dbuser = 'root'; 
$dbpass = ''; 
$dbname = 'moviefone';   
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con); 
// Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}    
$data = mysql_query(
"
SELECT * 
  FROM new_hindi 
  JOIN new_eng 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 4
 ") or die(mysql_error());    

 $info=array();    

 while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    $info[]=$row;    }    

?>
```

My problem is that it loops only the last data from the first table and from the second table it loops last four entry.what i want is that first table also loops the last four entry.

Comment: Note that this connection method is deprecated. See mysqli_ and/or PDO (and probably change your password). Now, how does `new_hindi` relate to `new_eng`?

Comment: I've seen mixing up of mysql_* and mysqli_*, the former shall be replaced.

Comment: hello Mike B no not really.

Comment: actually new_hindi is not at all related to new_eng.i have been trying to loop from multiple tables for different content on the same page.

Comment: Your query presently results in a cartesian product. Are you sure that that's what you want?

Comment: not really.i want to loop two different tables.how can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

While the library you are using is deprecated, and shouldn't be used for new projects (https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect), your problem lies in your join statement. You need to instruct SQL **how** you want to join the tables. Below is a generic example:

```
SELECT `field1` FROM `table1` INNER JOIN `table2` ON 
`table1`.`id` = `table2`.`table1_id` WHERE etc...
```

Cheers

Comment: what else can i use instead of INNER JOIN. I found out that i do not want to join the two tables.I want to loop two different table in the query.how can i do this ?

Comment: A correlated subquery. However, correlated subqueries carry a very heavy computational cost.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're after UNION...

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM new_hindi 
 UNION 
SELECT *
  FROM new_eng 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 4;
 ";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysqli_error());    

$info=array();    

 while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $info[]=$row;    
}
```

Comment: okay that is working fine with the first table.but for second table its showing undefined index .

Comment: well <img src="<?php echo $info[0]['eimage'];?>".that is what i am doing.i have three columns eid,eimage,etitle.